# Visual Studio 2012 and Team Foundation Services: Will not connect?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I am attempting to use Team Foundation Services (the cloud based service) with Visual Studio 2012 Update 1.

I have configured my account at visualstudio.com, and created a sample project.

When I click the "Open New Instance of Visual Studio" link from the Team Foundation Service project page:

- At home, my VS2012 opens and connects, and I can see the project in the Team panel.
- When controlling my work PC, VS2012 opens, but it does not connect.  The Team panel shows "Disconnected" where the project name should be.

How do I connect VS to Team Foundation Services when the "Open new Instance of Visual Studio" link does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just manually add a new server instance to Visual Studio. On the Team Explorer tab the 'Projects' menu item (click the <kbd>></kbd>) you should have a list of previously connected projects.

If the project you want isn't there, choose 'Connect to project'. Click the <kbd>servers</kbd> button to add `https://[youraccount].visualstudio.com/`.

Comment: It was switching to https from regular http that worked.  I had actuallly tried adding the regular URL before, and it failued.